# Where to reference Asp.net.Identity in my project architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, owin

This is the first time I'm creating a project architecture. I'm using code first approach and I want to use Identity for authentication and authorization.

I've creating following layers:

```
1- Project.Data - Application Context reside here.
2- Project.DTO - All ViewModels reside here.
3- Project.Entity - All Entities reside here.
4- Poject.Service - All interface and implementation reside here.
5- Project.API - Web API 2.0 reside here.
6- Project.UI - This is the Presentation Layer.
```

So, my question is:

```
- Do I need to reference ASP.Net Identity to each layer? 
- If Yes Why?
- If No Which Layer is suitable to reference Identity?
```

Comment: you need to reference in Project.Entity  Poject.Service - Project.API - Project.UI

Comment: programtreasures: Thanks but can you provide some explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*3- Project.Entity - All Entities reside here.-*

Need to add because you need to implement identity interfaces here to create asp.net identity entities

*1- Project.Data - Application Context reside here.*

Asp.net reference will not apply here, only applies the Project.Entity and you will only access the implemented types of asp.net identity

*2- Project.DTO - All ViewModels reside here.*

Here you have a projected types of entities and reconstructed types so asp.net identity will not applies here

*4- Poject.Service - All interface and implementation reside here.*

Here you need to implement business logic so you need asp.net identity reference

*5- Project.API - Web API 2.0 reside here.
6- Project.UI - This is the Presentation Layer.*

For those two layer you need to implement the authentication related stuffs so here also you need it